# Julia methoderror for eltype style functionality

Tags: debugging, julia

I have an abstract container `AbstractContainer` parameterised over a type `T` which indicates the type of what is in the container. Every subtype (in this case `FloatContainer`) then specifies what's actually in the container (in this case a `Float64`).

Ideally I'd have a means of getting back what type is in the container if I only have the container type.
This way I could use it in another struct (in this example `MultiplyBy`)

I was thinking of doing it in a similar way to Julia's internal `eltype` function but I can't get it to work.
I always get a method error (see the last snippet for the detailed error message)

```
abstract type AbstractContainer{T} end


gettype(::Type{AbstractContainer{T}}) where T = T

struct FloatContainer <: AbstractContainer{Float64}
  x::Float64
end


struct MultiplyBy{T<:AbstractContainer}
  x::gettype(T)
end


function process(m::MultiplyBy, v::AbstractContainer)
  return typeof(v)(m.x*v.x)
end


function main()
  x = FloatContainer(2.0)

  y = FloatContainer(3.0)
  op = MultiplyBy{FloatContainer}(y)

  z = process(op, x)
  println(z.x)
end


main()
```

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching gettype(::TypeVar)
Closest candidates are:
  gettype(!Matched::Type{AbstractContainer{T}}) where T at /Users/.../test.jl:6
```

I must admit I'm very new to Julia but I'm very interested in learning more about it.
So any tips are appreciated - either on how to solve this problem differently or where my mistake is.

Comment: Why do you want subtypes instead of just using the type parameter of the top level class to indicate what's in the container?

Answer (score 3):

### Determining element type

Your `gettype` does not work because it dispatches on abstract types, but your container objects will all have concrete types. You have to use the [subtype operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.:%3C:) in order to dispatch correctly.

Compare dispatch on abstract types:

```
julia> eltype1(::Type{AbstractContainer{T}}) where T = T
eltype1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> eltype1(FloatContainer)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching eltype1(::Type{FloatContainer})
Closest candidates are:
  eltype1(::Type{AbstractContainer{T}}) where T at REPL[4]:1
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[5]:1

julia> eltype1(AbstractContainer{Float64})
Float64
```

with dispatch on subtypes of abstract types:

```
julia> eltype2(::Type{<:AbstractContainer{T}}) where T = T
eltype2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> eltype2(FloatContainer)
Float64

julia> eltype2(AbstractContainer{Float64})
Float64
```

### Prefer dispatch variables to explicit `eltype` calls

Calling `eltype` directly is usually unnecessary; you can make the parametric type explicit during dispatch.

This solution uses only parametric types:

```
julia> struct Container{T}
           x::T
       end

julia> struct MultiplyBy{T}
           x::T
       end

julia> MulitplyBy(x::Container{T}) where T = MultiplyBy{T}(x.x)
MulitplyBy (generic function with 1 method)

julia> process(m::MultiplyBy, x::Container{T}) where T = Container{T}(m.x * x.x)
process (generic function with 1 method)

julia> a = Container(2.0)
Container{Float64}(2.0)

julia> b = Container(3.0)
Container{Float64}(3.0)

julia> op = MulitplyBy(b)
MultiplyBy{Float64}(3.0)

julia> process(op, a)
Container{Float64}(6.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure about what you need, but i coded an working example with your structure:

```
abstract type AbstractContainer{T} end

#not necessary anymore
#gettype(a::Type{AbstractContainer{T}})  where T = T

struct FloatContainer{T<:AbstractFloat} <: AbstractContainer{T} #AbstractFloat, to include Float32, BigFloats and others
  x::T
end

 #you can't use functions on struct definitions, if you need more restrictions,
 #use a Constructor
struct MultiplyBy{T<:AbstractContainer}
  x::T
end

#example external Constructor

MultiplyBy(x::AbstractFloat) = MultiplyBy(FloatContainer(x))

value(x::AbstractContainer) = x.x #basic accesor function
value(x::MultiplyBy) = value(x.x) 

function process(m::MultiplyBy, v::AbstractContainer)
  return typeof(v)(value(m)*value(v)) #calling accesor functions to access the values.
end

function main()
  x = FloatContainer(2.0)

  y = FloatContainer(3.0)
  op = MultiplyBy(y) #the parametric type is inferred automatically, no need to use Curly Braces

  z = process(op, x)
  println(value(x)) #better use accesor functions that direct access, as the underlying implementation can change
end

main()
```